# How do I validate an msal token from Microsoft Single Sign-On in ASP.Net Core using JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ValidateToken

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, jwt, openid-connect, azure-ad-msal

I am currently attempting to Validate a token I have extracted from my web site's cookie.

According to the docos I can retrieve the public keys from [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{my](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Bmy) tenant guid}/discovery/v2.0/keys?client_id={my client guid}
(Is this right? Is client_id acceptable? I don't have an appid in my config, and it didn't seem to make a difference anyway!)

I am not sure how to populate the token validation parameters in the code below. I have tried all sorts of variations. It doesn't complain about the Audience or Issuer, only the key doesn't match. Where does that come from in msal?

How can I Validate the token?

I have the following code:

```
var httpContext = context.GetHttpContext();
var cookies = httpContext.Request.Cookies;
var msalIdToken = cookies["msal." + this._clientId + ".idtoken"];
if (msalIdToken != null)
{
    var validationParams = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidAudience= "my ClientId guid",
        ValidIssuer= "https://login.microsoftonline.com/my tenant guid/v2.0",
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"???Not sure where to get this from"))//,
        ,TryAllIssuerSigningKeys=true
    };

    SecurityToken validatedToken;
    var identity = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ValidateToken(msalIdToken, validationParams, out validatedToken);
```

Answer (score 1):

You download token signing keys from a JWKS URL - you will only need to supply this URL to the MS framework and it will do the rest for you.

Here is the JWKS URL for my developmemt tenant:

- https://login.microsoftonline.com/7f071fbc-8bf2-4e61-bb48-dabd8e2f5b5a/discovery/v2.0/keys

I would get to know the token details a bit, outside of your API's code. In particular check that the issuer is the one you expect and that there is no `nonce` field in the JWT header - this type of token will always fail validation in your own APIs.

**FURTHER INFO**

A couple of my blog posts may help you to get on top of this:

- [Validating Azure AD tokens in online tools](https://authguidance.com/2017/12/06/azure-ad-api-token-validation/)
- [Troubleshooting Azure AD Tokens](https://authguidance.com/2017/12/01/azure-ad-spa-code-sample/)